# Lua in xcode doesn`t work

Tags: xcode, lua

[image: Build logs]

I am running Xcode 7.0 and Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Could you post your Xcode target configuration? It seems that you have issues in **Linking Settings**

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-llua` in **Other Linker Flags** in **Linking** section of your target settings.